# c# Type Inference

Tags: c#, type-inference

I have an ECMContext class that inherits from DbContext.  Within ECMContext there is a property `MlaArticles` which is `DbSet<MlaArticle>` where `MlaArticle` is inherited from `WebObject`.  I have created a generic method that accepts an argument of type WebObject. The method tries to save changes to the db and if not, backs out the changes.

My question - since I already have db (which was already instantiated) and I know the type of `WebObject` that is being passed (`MlaArticle` in this example), is there a way to refer to the DbSet collection `db.MlaArticles` without passing an extra argument? I know this is wrong but this exemplifies my question...

```
protected ECMContext db;

void SaveChanges<T>(T obj) where T : WebObject 
{
    try { db.SaveChanges(); }
    catch
    {
        db.MlaArticles.Remove(obj); //this is the original code
        db.DbSet<T>.Remove(obj); //something like this is what I'd like to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the `Set<T>()` operation:

```
try { db.SaveChanges(); }
catch
{
    db.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
}
```

?